# How do I perform Chi-Squared test on categorical variable?

Tags: r, chi-squared, hypothesis-test

This might be a question that could be answered relatively quickly if I knew more terminology.

Am I correctly performing a chi-squared test for independence on the `JOB` variable?

```
CD %>% select(JOB, DEFAULT) %>%
table() %>% chisq.test()
```

```
unique(CD$JOB)
[1] SkilledEmployee/Official                         
[2] Unemployed/Unskilled:Resident                    
[3] Mgr/SelfEmployed/HighlyQualified Employee/Officer
[4] Unemployed/Unskilled:NonResident   
              
4 Levels
```

Thank You.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at `?chisq.test` and to pass the relevant arguments to the function appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Almost got it right.
Null hypothesis would be that the categics are independent.
H1 would be they are not independent.

Run the test like this, there is no need for dplyr::select on the df CD.

```
chisq.test(table(CD$JOB,CD$DEFAULT))
```

Comment: Does the use of dplyr slow down the processing?

Comment: probably only marginal (also this is R so its slow anyways) It also works as intended, but it just looks weird.

Comment: ah okay! hilarious. Thank you. So, to be clear, the output p value for my test would then tell me if I should keep the entire variable/discard it, correct? (I am feature selecting).

Comment: if p is low (<0.05) means H0 holds true, that means variables are probably independent . what variables to discard or not depends more on your question than on the math tbh.

Comment: I was worried that, since it's categorical and not binary, the p value would have a different meaning that normal.

Comment: This is a really useful reaource if your not sure which statistical method is appropriate https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly what you want in the way you thought by using `chi_test()` from `rstatix` package.

I strongly recommend checking out `rstatix`. This package makes baseR operation pipe-friendly. So if you like pipe, you will love it.

**Solution**

```r
library(rstatix)

CD %>%
  select(JOB, DEFAULT) %>% 
  table() %>% 
  chisq_test()
```